# Trying to understand an FFT

Tags: java, audio, fft

So I am working on something of a challenging project for myself. I am currently running a Fast Fourier Transform algorithm on an array of sound data. The algorithm I'm using puts out complex numbers as the resulted converted data. I need to take that information and use it to determine what frequency each piece in the original array is.

I've been teaching myself how to write all this code for recording and analyzing sound but I've come to a point where Google can't seem to help me. If you have any ideas of how I can proceed I would deeply appreciate it!

Comment: You should actually ask a question then. What exactly are you stuck with?

Answer (score 1):

After running the FFT, the frequency values can be obtained be taking the absolute value of the real and imaginary components squared. (abs(real^2 + imag^2))

Now how do you know what frequency value that magnitude corresponds to?
Eg: if you run a 128 point fft, you will get a range of complex numbers, 128 in total, ranging from 0Hz to the sampling frequency (one of the parameters when doing a fft). And so each complex number corresponds to a frequency value, going up in steps of (sampling frequency/128), starting at 0Hz.

Hope this helps!